# whoami returns user, but usermod complains it doesn't exist

Tags: ubuntu, users, authorization, usermod

I have Linux (Ubuntu) on a VM provided by corporate IT in my organization,
and I have a user "myuser".

`whoami` is able to return the username:

```
myuser@host:/home/myuser$ whoami
myuser
```

`id` returns info related to the user too:

```
myuser@host:~$ id
uid=43350(myuser) gid=600(staff) groups=600(staff),27(sudo)
```

And `getent` returns my user in the list,
but `/etc/passwd` doesn't have my user's entry.

Now I am trying to run docker commands without sudo. So I tried adding the user to the group, but usermod says user does not exist

```
myuser@host:/home/myuser$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
usermod: user 'myuser' does not exist
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you know where your user is defined? (I.e., locally / on a central server?)

Comment: It's not local... /etc/passwd doesnt have my user's entry but getent returns my user in the list

Comment: I have the same issue, were you able to solve it ? my user is also not defined locally